# Changing the Contents of a Pandas Column Based on Another Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, mapping

I have a pandas dataframe similar to the following:

```
Neighborhood      High School      ...
WOODLEY           LIBERTY
WOODLEY 
COUNTRY CLUB  
COUNTRY CLUB      HERITAGE
COUNTRY CLUB      HERITAGE
COUNTRY CLUB      TUSCORORA
...
```

As you can see, some of the entries are either blank or incorrect, so I am trying to fix these. I began by creating a function like the following.

```
def cleanHS(dat):
    if dat.Neighborhood == "WOODLEY":
        dat["High School"] == "LIBERTY"
    elif dat.Neighborhood == "COUNTRY CLUB":
        dat["High School"] == "HERITAGE"
    ...

    return dat
```

I then call the function.

```
dirty["High School"] = dirty["High School"].map(cleanHS)
```

This is where I receive an attribute error:
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Neighborhood'`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the correct answer. Using a dictionary to map is easy (as shown in another answer).

```
cleanHS = {"WOODLEY": "LIBERTY", "COUNTRY CLUB": "HERITAGE", ...}
```

However, in order to properly map the two columns, the neighborhood column must be included. This is because you are mapping the values from High School to other values, but your starting column from which to map values should be Neighborhood.

```
dirty["High School"] = dirty["Neighborhood"].map(cleanHS)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a loop here. You can create a dictionary of key-value pairs going from `Neighbourhood` and [mapping](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to corrected values for `High School`

```
d = {"WOODLEY": "LIBERTY", "COUNTRY CLUB": "HERITAGE"}
dirty['High School'] = dirty['Neighborhood'].map(d)
```

Output

```
Neighborhood      High School
WOODLEY           LIBERTY
WOODLEY           LIBERTY
COUNTRY CLUB      HERITAGE
COUNTRY CLUB      HERITAGE
COUNTRY CLUB      HERITAGE
COUNTRY CLUB      HERITAGE
```